# ActionMailer - Sending email with Google Apps doesn't work, but works with free Gmail account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, gmail, actionmailer, google-apps

When I try send some email using a Google Apps account I receive this error:

> EOFError: end of file reached

Using a free Gmail account the email is send successfully.

It's my Mailer config:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    domain: "devsup.com.br'",
    user_name: "admin@devsup.com.br",
    password: "password",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    authentication: "plain"
}
```

Somebody have some ideia what I must to do? There's some config that I must do in my Google Apps account?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a similar issue. Try setting the domain to `gmail.com`, like this:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    domain: "gmail.com",
    user_name: "admin@devsup.com.br",
    password: "password",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    authentication: "plain"
}
```

EDIT:
Or try to make sure to remove the typo in the domain. There is an extra single quote in your domain right now.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't see the single quote in my domain. It's was very helpful. :)